# Find numerical solution of (overdetermined) system of differential(-algebraic) equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am attempting to find numerical solutions to a system of differential equations I found. First off, these are the two relevant functions:

```
f[t_] := 0.2856366975757554*Cos[3.141592653589793*(0.3295 - 0.0002*Tan[1.560831139643837*Erf[0.2*(-15 + t)]])]^(1/4);
g[t_] := -(111/20) + 6*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[Cos[3.141592653589793*(0.3295 - 0.0002*Tan[1.560831139643837*Erf[0.2*(-15 + t)]])]];
k = 2*Sqrt[3];
```

The actual system of differential equations is given by

```
eqs0 = { (* this is the actual system of ODEs *)
   f[t]*Cos[k*h1[t]] - g[t]/k*Sin[k*h1[t]] + h2'[t] == 0,
   g[t]/k*Sin[k*h2[t]] + h1'[t] == 0,
   h1[t]*h2'[t] - h1'[t]*h2[t] == 0
   };
```

where I need to find `h1[t]` and `h2[t]`. From the nature of the problem I safely know that `h1[t]!=0` so that I may use the third equation to reduce the total number of equations, which will turn the problem into a system of differential-algebraic equations:

```
eqs1 = { (* here I used the last equation of eqs0 to reduce the number of equations *)
   f[t]*Cos[k*h1[t]] - g[t]/k*Sin[k*h1[t]] + h2[t]/h1[t]*h1'[t] == 0,
   g[t]/k*Sin[k*h2[t]] + h1'[t] == 0
   };
```

The initial conditions for the problem are unfortunately not too clear, but it does definitely make sense to demand `h2[0]==0`. Apart from that, I actually know nothing about `h2[t]` - it is completely open how this function will look like. There is an initial condition for `h1[0]` (and similarly one for `h1'[0]`) based on physical thoughts, but I would not consider it too strong - so I came up with two possible initial conditions, given by

```
initial1 = { (* motivated by the physical problem, yet the condition for h1 is not mandatory *)
   h1[0] == ArcTan[k*f[0]/g[0]]/k,
   h2[0] == 0
   };

initial2 = { (* another initial condition that might be more compatible with eqs1 *)
   h1[0] == First@(h1[0] /. NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, h2[0] == 0}], {h1, h2}, {t, 0, 0}]),
   h2[0] == 0
   };
```

Attempting to run `NDSolve` on `eqs0` of course leads to a complaint because the system is overdetermined, so I tried on `eqs1`:

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial1}], {h1, h2}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

> NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations.
>
> NDSolve::index: The DAE solver failed at t = 0.`. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE index is 2. The option Method->{"IndexReduction"->Automatic} may be used to reduce the index of the system.

So, as suggested by the second warning, I change the `Method` which does also yield the differential-algebraic hint but also a convergence issue:

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial1}], {h1, h2}, {t, 0, 30}, Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}];
```

> NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.`; unable to continue.

If I switch to the second set of initial conditions (which I assume to be more compatible with the system), I receive a warning about the initial conditions. However, I am unsure how to specify initial values for the derivatives... If I went with `initial1` I could make a guess for `h1'[0]` but that's all.

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial2}], {h1, h2}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

> NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.

As I am by far no expert on solving such kind of equations in general and especially not in Mathematica: How would I need to proceed in order to find solutions for the two functions in question, `h1[t]` and `h2[t]`?

Comment: Knowing that `h1[t] h2'[t] - h1'[t] h2[t] == 0` (the third equation) it implies that `h2[t] == c2 h1[t]` where `c2` is a constant. So your problem isn't especially hard to tackle with.

Comment: @Artes Thank you very much for the suggestion. Is it possible to see why this is the only possible solution to the third equation?

Comment: Check `D[ h2[t]/h1[t], t]`,  since the third equation is equivalent under general circumstances to `D[ h2[t]/h1[t], t] == 0`, this implies that  `h2[t]/h1[t]` does not depend on `t`.

Comment: @Artes Thanks alot for the explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That first set of initial conditions works well with the case where we simply drop the third DE.

```
f[t_] := 0.2856366975757554*
   Cos[3.141592653589793*(0.3295 - 
        0.0002*Tan[1.560831139643837*Erf[0.2*(-15 + t)]])]^(1/4);
g[t_] := -(111/20) + 
   6*Sqrt[3]*
    Sqrt[Cos[
      3.141592653589793*(0.3295 - 
         0.0002*Tan[1.560831139643837*Erf[0.2*(-15 + t)]])]];
k = 2*Sqrt[3];
```

Here I remove that last DE and instead regard it as a constraint.

```
eqs1 = {f[t]*Cos[k*h1[t]] - g[t]/k*Sin[k*h1[t]] + h2'[t] == 0, 
   g[t]/k*Sin[k*h2[t]] + h1'[t] == 0};
constraint = h1[t]*h2'[t] - h1'[t]*h2[t] == 0;
```

We will solve the system and check afterwards whether the constraint happened to be enforced.

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial1}], {h1, h2}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

Let's see how the solutions appear.

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Evaluate[{h1[t]} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[{h2[t]} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image: solutions]

Now we visually check the error in that constraint.

```
Plot[constraint[[1]] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image: constraint error]

One possible way to improve on this would be to use `Method -> "Projection"` to enforce the constraint as an invariant. To make this work I needed to get rid of explicit derivatives in the constraint equation.

```
newconstraint = constraint /. First[Solve[eqs1, {h1'[t], h2'[t]}]];
solProj = 
 NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial1}], {h1[t], h2[t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
  Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {newconstraint[[1]]}}]
```

The plot is a bit different now.

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Evaluate[{h1[t]} /. solProj[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[{h2[t]} /. solProj[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image: solutions]

And the error is almost an order of magnitude reduced.

```
Plot[newconstraint[[1]] /. solProj[[1]], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: constraint error]

Increasing `AccuracyGoal` beyond default will bring this down even more. Here is a variant that remained reasonably fast and gave another order of magnitude improvement on the constraint violation.

```
solProj = 
 NDSolve[Join[{eqs1, initial1}], {h1[t], h2[t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
  Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {newconstraint[[1]]}}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 20]

Plot[newconstraint[[1]] /. solProj[[1]], {t, 0, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: constraint error]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Especially the projection method as a tool to enforce the constraint was new and very useful for this kind of problem